# Is there a "safe" way to declare a lippincott function so that it won't be called outside of a catch?

Tags: c++, function, exception, c++17

A [Lippincott function](http://cppsecrets.blogspot.com/2013/12/using-lippincott-function-for.html) is a function which converts an exception into a return code that can be safely handled in a callback from another language which did not support exceptions, such as C.  Such functions, because they deliberately use `throw` with no argument, thereby rethrowing the most recently caught exception, cannot be called outside the context of a `catch` block.

I am wondering if modern C++ (c++17 or c++20) has any declaration mechanism for specifically identifying such functions, and ensuring that a function is only ever called from the context of a `catch` block (or from the context of another such function), generating a compile time error if it is called from any other context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to tell the compiler that a particular function should only be called from a `catch` handler.

You can, however, call `std::current_exception()` from within your Lippincott function to determine if there currently an exception being handled.  If this returns a `nullptr` then there is no exception active.  You can then handle this at runtime by triggering an assert and/or having your function return (and not use throw).

Answer (score 2):

There is no compile time syntax to inform that a function must only be called when there exists a current exception. It can only be detected at runtime, whether such current exception does exist.

You could use higher-order programming, and instead of providing the `lippincott` function, provide a wrapper which does the entire try-call-catch-lippincott for a given function:

```
auto with_catch = [](auto&& f, auto&& c, auto&&... args) -> decltype(c()) {
    try {
        f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        return {};
    } catch (...) {
        return c();
    }
};

auto with_lippincott = [](auto&& f, auto&&... args) {
    return with_catch(
        std::forward<decltype(f)>(f),
        lippincott,
        std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...
    );
};
```

This is not so easy to misuse. Usage example:

```
foo_Result r3 = with_lippincott(Snafuscate, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to enforce that at compile time.
In the same way that the compiler does not ensure that bare `throw` (rethrow) must be called inside a `catch`-block.

(Note that in the Lippincott function `throw` is inside a `try`-block not a `catch`-block.)

However static analysis tools like `cppcheck` 2.5 or maybe `clang-tidy` can detect these uses of bare `throw` outside catch, so they might be able to also detect misuses of `lippincott()`.